# Activar camara con c#

Tags: c#

Hola soy un poco nuevo en esto

Estoy realizando un desarrollo con MVC y C#, ya tengo publicada mi pagina web en un servidor IIS mi intención es que la pagina cuando se ingrese con un dispositivo móvil pueda activar la cámara con C#

¿Es posible esto?

Alguien que me pueda dar un ejemplo

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La unica forma que conozco es por medio de `html5` usando

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

pero basicamente seria un upload de la grabacion por eso el `type="file"`

[Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: con el link que compartiste pude resolverlo.... gracias

Comment: gracias por el link ya logre hacerlo